# Why is my VueJs component not showing in the frontend?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

I am trying to implement vuejs in a current django project.
It kind of worked. However I wanted a cleaner structure and use vuejs components.

However the components are not showing up in the frontend.

So here I have my basic vue component (from the vueify-laravel example)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello, {{ name }}</h1>
        <input type="text" v-model="name">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                name: 'Laracasts'
            };
        }
    };
</script>

<style>
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

In my app.js I have

```
var Vue = require('vue')
import Greeter from './components/Greeter.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    components: {
        greeter: Greeter
    }
});
```

And finally in one of my django templates

```
<div id="app">
    <greeter></greeter>
</div>
```

I have vue dev tools installed, and it shows me the root node and then the greeter node. But nothing in it. And the app container is empty too.

Comment: The code seems to be ok. Please, check your `browserify` options.

Answer (score 11):

If the template is coming from django then you have to escape the `{{` and `}}`. To turn off the template parsing use `{% verbatim %}` or you can also use `{% templatetag openvariable %}` (and then closevariable).

try:

```
{% verbatim %}
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello, {{ name }}</h1>
        <input type="text" v-model="name">
    </div>
</template>
{% endverbatim %}
```

Comment: Yeah, but the problem was, that nothing showed up. Not even the input.

However it was a problem with vueify. :)

Comment: You should post the answer and close the question then. And a +1 never hurt anybody.